# Encrypt Notes Database programmatically

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus

I need to build a tool that can Encrypt databases on server.

So far I have found this info (but that's not enough).

1. It's possible to check if database encrypted (works only locally) using NSFDbIsLocallyEncrypted.
2. Make a replica W32_NSFDbCreateAndCopy and set Encryption while creating replica (that will be applied on replica).
3. There is an undocumented Notes C API call that sets encryption flag for compact, but I could not make that work.

   STATUS far PASCAL NSFDbLocalSecInfoSet(DBHANDLE hDB, WORD Option, BYTE EncryptStrength, char far *Username);
4. I have also read it is possible (for older ODS version) to change 'icon note' or to use DBINFO3 for newer ODS version (I could not make it work as well)

Does anybody know how to solve this task?

p.s. I have been told that HCL will come with proper solution in future (but not sure when).

Comment: Why encrypt on the server? With whose ID? If the database is encrypted with your ID, the server will no longer be able to decrypt it. The server is supposed to be in a safe location, so no need for encryption. You can always encrypt network traffic.

Comment: @D.Bugger you are right, however it's a request from a customer.

Comment: You can (and should) encrypt with the server's ID.  The downside is that to make it useful, you need to put a password on the id file, which means that to recover from a restart, someone needs to type in the password from the console (ask me how I know.)  You could reduce the security slightly by having a blank password, but some policies don't allow that.  "The server is supposed to be safe..." Famous last words.

Comment: "The server is supposed to be safe..."... Not my words ;-)

Comment: I can understand the necessity when a Domino server is installed somewhere in the cloud. Here a similar question: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd85forum.nsf/DateAllFlatWeb/78b281e0aacd05d385257bd3001388f4?OpenDocument

Comment: BCC have a product that will allow a server to restart with a password set on the server ID, (as hinted at in Richard Moys answer). Server data/database encryption is a compliance issue/requirement and provides better data protection at the expense of speed and possibly backup complexity. On disk encryption prevents the data file and any backup copies of the NSF from being inspected (try opening an unencrypted NSF in wordpad to see what I mean). Also minimises partial cluster buffer data on shared servers and other 'data bleed' issues. Always encrypt any private/confidential data if possible!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is working code. I could not figure out, what to set as EncrytionStrength to remove local encryption using this code.

```
%REM
Agent encrypt
Created Dec 22, 2019 by Ulrich Krause/singultus
Description: Comments for Agent
%END REM
Option Public
Option Declare

Public Const W32_LIB = {nnotes.dll}
Declare Function W32_NSFDbCompactExtended Lib W32_LIB Alias {NSFDbCompactExtended}  (ByVal Pathname As String, Options As Long, retStats As Long) As Integer
Declare Function W32_NSFDbLocalSecInfoSet Lib W32_LIB Alias {NSFDbLocalSecInfoSet} (ByVal hDb As Long, ByVal wOptions As Integer, ByVal EncryptStrength As Integer, ByVal Username As String) As Integer
Declare Function W32_NSFDbIsLocallyEncrypted Lib W32_LIB Alias {NSFDbIsLocallyEncrypted} ( ByVal hDB As Long, V As Integer) As Integer
Declare Sub W32_OSLoadString Lib W32_LIB Alias {OSLoadString} (ByVal null1 As Long, ByVal sError As Integer, ByVal errstr As String, ByVal lenstr As Integer)
Declare Function W32_NSFDbOpen Lib W32_LIB Alias {NSFDbOpen}(ByVal dbName As String, hDb As Long) As Integer
Declare Function W32_NSFDbClose Lib W32_LIB Alias {NSFDbClose} (ByVal hDb As Long) As Integer
Sub Initialize
Dim hDb As Long
Dim rc As Integer
Dim sDb As String
Dim retStats As Long

sDb = "serv01/singultus!!crash.nsf"

rc = W32_NSFDbOpen(sDb, hDb)

If rc = 0 Then
    rc = W32_NSFDbLocalSecInfoSet(hDb, 0,1, "")
    msgbox GetError(rc)

    If rc = 0 Then
        rc = W32_NSFDbCompactExtended (sDb, 0, retStats)
    End if
    rc = W32_NSFDbClose(hDb)
End If
End Sub
Function GetError (errnum As Integer) As String
Dim s As String*256
If IsDefined("WINDOWS") Then
    W32_OSLoadString 0, errnum And &h03FFFFFFF, s, 256
Else
    'TUX_OSLoadString 0, errnum And &h03FFFFFFF, s, 256
End If
getError = StrLeft(s, Chr(0))
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You should look into the BCC solution DominoProtect or Ulrich Krause had other solution, Having database encryption on the server is a requirement for many compliance situations.